# Passing derived classes inside map to function in C++

Tags: c++, function, oop, parameter-passing

I would like to have a function that accepts a `std::map` containing a (pointer to a) base class, but I can't get it to work. Here is my minimal and simplified example:

```cpp
struct Entity {
  int i;

  Entity(const int i_) : i(i_) {}
  virtual ~Entity() {}
};

struct A : public Entity {
  bool a;
  A(const int i_, const bool a_) : Entity(i_), a(a_) {}
};

void efunc(const std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Entity>>& m) {
  for (auto& it : m) {
    std::cout << it.second->i << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<A>> aMap;
  std::shared_ptr<A> myA = std::make_shared<A>(1, true);
  aMap.insert({myA->i, myA});

  // efunc(aMap);  // DOES NOT WORK
}
```

Obviously simply passing the `map` this way is not allowed, but how can I make it work?

As a bonus, how would I detect the type in the map so that I can execute code specific to that subclass?

Thank you in advance!

**Update:** Using templates seems to do the trick, this is what I'm using right now:

```cpp
template <class T>
void tfunc(const std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<T>>& m) {
  for (auto& it : m) {
    std::cout << it.second->i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

It does *feel* a bit strange, since I loose IntelliSense and I don't understand why the compiler is not giving me an error. I feel like `concept`s might help (e.g. to make sure `T` inherits `Entity`), but this is beyond what I need right now.

Thank you again for all the responses!

**Update 2:** Alright, here it is using concepts to ensure that the `template` containst the member `i`:

```cpp
template <class T>
concept hasI = requires(T a) { a.i; };

template <class T>
concept inheritsEntity = std::derived_from<T, Entity>;

template <hasI T>  
/// alternative: template<inheritsEntity T>
void tfunc(const std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<T>>& m) {
  for (auto& it : m) {
    std::cout << it.second->i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: You basically have three options: (1) change the signature of `efunc`, (2) change the type of `aMap`, (3) add a conversion (which will either perform a shallow copy or, if you write a suitable adapter type, performs no copy but translates on the fly).

Comment: To ask the obvious question: is making `efunc` a function template an option for you?

Comment: And to answer your second functions: by defining suitable virtual functions in the base class which are overridden with the specific functionality in the subclasses.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I have never used templates before. So beside templates making my head spin, is there another reason not to use them? I'm not sure how I would implement this here, though. :/

Comment: @HuyNhatTran Yeah, I think something like this is the best approach for this, as has been suggested (and then argued against) before.

Comment: The good news: your code is *already* using templates (`std::map` is a template)! :-) — And you will *need* to learn to use templates if you want to use C++ effectively, so now is as good a time as ever. I see you managed to solve your problem, which is great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, you could use *template programming*; the compiler will generate the code specific to the required type for you:

```cpp
template <class EntityType> 
void efunc_template(const std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<EntityType>>& m) {
  for (auto& it : m) {
    std::cout << it.second->i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

The function can then be called in your `main` function using:

```
efunc_template<A>(aMap);
```

Regarding your second question (how to execute code specific to your type), check can be done at compile time using:

```
template <class EntityType> 
void efunc_template(const std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<EntityType>>& m) {
  for (auto& it : m) {
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<A, EntityType>) {
      std::cout << "Type is A" << std::endl;
    } else {
      std::cout << "Other type: " << typeid(EntityType).name() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << it.second->i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: If we have a simple runtime polymorphic solution which uses virtual functions, there is really no need for using a template at all. This answer goes fully to the wrong direction! My two cents!

Comment: Thanks, I think this is it. There seems to be a philosophical debate in this thread whether or not using templates for this is "bad practice", but I'm amazed how simple it is and does what I want. I have to admit I don't quite get why the compiler is not complaining, but I think I can live with that for now. :)

Comment: As mentioned by @Klaus this solution is hackish as it mixes a runtime polymorphism- and template- based one. This solution does the job if you don't want to modify the `efunc` fonction calls. As suggested by @Konrad Rudolph, the `if constexpr` if also not so cleaned, and can be replaced using virtual functions. Have a look at the L-principle on the SOLID page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). Also, if you don't know about template, have a look at a good c++ book (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can make `aMap` a `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Entity>>` and still hold shared pointers to instances of `A`.

In the code below `myA` which will be stored in the map is of type `std::shared_ptr<Entity>` but is initialized with a shared pointer to an instance of class `A`. This is OK because `A` is derived from `Entity`.

```
//----------------------------VVVVVV--------
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Entity>> aMap;

//--------------VVVVVV-------------------------V-----------
std::shared_ptr<Entity> myA = std::make_shared<A>(1, true);

aMap.insert({ myA->i, myA });

efunc(aMap);  // Works now.
```

As commented below, `myA` can also be `std::shared_ptr<A>` and still be stored in `aMap`:

```
std::shared_ptr<A> myA = std::make_shared<A>(1, true);
```

---

Alternatively, if using `efunc` is quite rare, you can keep `aMap` as `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<A>>`.
Then whenever you need to call `efunc`, create a temporary `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Entity>>` containing a copy of the content of `aMap` and use it to call `efunc`.
The shared pointers will still refer to your original objects.
It's inefficient, but if you don't use `efunc` frequently it might be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, except then i have to cast the the pointers of `myA` to the right type every time I use them elsewhere (which happens a lot more). By the way, when changing the map type to `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Entity>>`, adding a `std::shared_ptr<A>` still works.

Comment: It's not efficient, but if it happens rarely can solve your original issue by creating a temporary `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Entity>>` _copy_ from your `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<A>>` just for calling `efunc`.

Comment: Creating another copy would be the easiest to write solution, but it would be called `O(n^2)` times, I would like to avoid it.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution. Maybe something can be done but it requires deeper and broader understanding of your system.

Answer (score -1):

Change the declaration of your std::map variable from :

```
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<A>> aMap;
```

to :

```
std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Entity>> aMap;
```

This way, the map matches what's expected by your efunc function.

Using inheritance as you did, you can indeed insert in your aMap data structure  instances of type Entity as well as instances whose the type derivates from Entity. This is the case for struct A.

To detect the type in the map, you can either use a scoped enum as member within the Entity struct, or using the [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) operator, which returns an instance of std::type_info, with which you can get the name of the type.

However, the returned name is not guaranteed to be the same across implementations.

> ======== output from Clang ========
>
> myint has type: i
>
> mystr has type: NSt3__112basic_stringIcNS_11char_traitsIcEENS_9allocatorIcEEEE

> ======== output from MSVC ========
>
> myint has type: int
>
> mystr has type: class std::basic_string<char,struct > std::char_traits,class std::allocator >

For this reason, you might want to use dynamic_cast instead, such as :

```
class Base {
    public:
        virtual ~Base() {}
};

class T1Base : public Base {};
class T2Base : public Base {};

template <typename T> class T1 : public T1Base {};
template <typename T> class T2 : public T2Base {};

int main()
{
    Base *b = find_by_name();

    if (dynamic_cast<T1Base*>(b))
        cout << "T1" << endl;
    else if (dynamic_cast<T2Base*>(b))
        cout << "T2" << endl;
    else
        cout << "unknown" << endl;

    delete b;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When the answer is `dynamic_cast` or `typeid`, you are usually asking the wrong question. In particular, I don't see how this would help OP.

Comment: Thanks for replying and your example! Changing the map to `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<Entity>>` means I have to cast the entries in all other occasions (which is the vast majority), so I'm not too fond of this and probably would just copy the function for the different inherited types (which is relatively small). Regarding the example: is there a reason to use templates instead of trying a `dynamic_cast` and see if it is null?

Comment: @Markstar If you need to cast the *entities* (rather than the map) this indicates a flaw in your object design. In most cases you shouldn't need to cast within class hierarchies *at all* (I'm aware that there are exceptions but, well, these should be *exceptions*). The whole point of inheritance is that the client code can use the the implementations interchangeably via the base class interface.

Comment: dynamic_cast is a first hint for very bad design and in the given scenario not needed nor helpful.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Hmm, I'm using this to import data from a csv file. The file may contain different kinds of objects, which I have thouroughly verify, cast, create implied objects, and a lot more before I can add the final object. While the objects may have some similarities (e.g. a name, though even there two diffent types of object may have the same name), they are totally different in other regards. So I don't see how I can make it so all objects implment the same  set of virtual functions.